# MVVM Tutorial/Example Code with internet connectivity

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I understand the View and ViewModel portions of MVVM, but what I'm still really fuzzy on is how you connect your application to data sources on the Internet (say you're grabbing some XML or JSON from the web), and specifically, where that code goes in your application. Can someone provide or link to some example code or a tutorial that walks you through setting up a simple WPF (or Silverlight) application that fetches data from the Web?

Comment: I haven't seen such a thing.  But the beauty of using MVVM is that separation of concerns means separation of problems:  if you know MVVM, once you know how to build an object that exposes properties that it retrieves from (say) a web service, you already know how to build a presentation layer for it.  You should really just be looking for good examples of WCF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Josh Smith has a [small section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090102) in his MVVM article about the repository pattern.

Basically, he says you have a Repository that connects to your Internet data source, which pulls the data down into your ViewModel.  Your Repository can contain a HttpWebRequest to your XML or Json source.  Then format it into your ViewModel.

Here is [another example](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Data-Driven-Applications-with-MVVM-Part-I.-The-Basics.aspx) that shows you how to mock out your data source.

Comment: A little over-engineered for what I need, but it provided a good start, thanks. :)

Comment: If it is a bit much, you can always slim it down to just a HttpWebRequest followed by a parse.  Then you would fill your ViewModel.